# TypeError: forward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'size'

Tags: python, yolov5

with mss() as sct:
monitor = {"top": 220, "left": 640, "width": 640, "height":640}

```
while(True):
    size =640
    screenshot = np.array(sct.grab(monitor))
    results = model(screenshot,size=640)
    df= results.pandas().xyxy[0]
```

```
I'm having a problem running a script...
together with yolov5

  File "D:\Users\Guto\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1190, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
TypeError: forward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'size'
```

```
with mss() as sct:
    monitor = {"top": 220, "left": 640, "width": 640, "height":640}

    while(True):
        size =640
        screenshot = np.array(sct.grab(monitor))
        results = model(screenshot,size=640)
        df= results.pandas().xyxy[0]
```

I'm having a problem running a script...
together with yalov5

File "D:\Users\Guto\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1190, in _call_impl
return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
TypeError: forward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'size'